# YouTube Data API のJSON データの datetime 値を Gson で扱うには

Tags: android, json, youtube-data-api

YouTube Data API から取得した､データを Gson を使ってパースしようとしているのですが､対応するクラスについて､一つ疑問があります｡[リファレンス](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search?hl=ja#resource)を拝見すると `publishedAt` の型は､ `datetime` となっていますが､次の例のように､ Gson では `Date` 型で当てはめてもいいのでしょうか､

**コード:**

```java
public class Snippet {
    public Date publishedAt;
    public String title;
    public String description;
    public Thumbnails thumbnails;
}
```

これを実行したところ､独自に作成した `CustomAdapter` で以下の `NullPointerException` が出てしまいました｡

**エラー:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
```

**CustomAdapter:**

```java
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Items> {
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private RequestQueue mQueue;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Items> objects, RequestQueue queue){
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(queue, new LruCacheClass());
}

static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView image;
    TextView title;
    TextView maker;
    TextView numView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder;
    Items item = getItem(position);
    String url = item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;

    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_search, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_thumbnail);
        holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_movie_title);
        holder.maker = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_maker);
        holder.numView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_day_num_view);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    ImageLoader.ImageListener listener = ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.image,
            android.R.drawable.spinner_background,
            android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);

    mImageLoader.get(url, listener);

    holder.title.setText(item.snippet.title);
    holder.maker.setText(item.channelTitle);
    //この行でNullPointerExceptionがでてしまう｡
    holder.numView.setText(sdf.format(item.snippet.publishedAt.getTime()));

    return convertView;
}
}
```

また､ `publishedAt` でタイムゾーンに依存させたいので､[こちら](http://www30304u.sakura.ne.jp/blog/?p=2577)のサイトを参考にして Gson を編集しています｡

**BuildGson:**

```java
import com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

/**
 * Created by zousan on 2015/01/25.
 */
public class BuildGson {
public static Gson buildGsonForPublishedAt() {
    GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();

    gb.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDeserializer<Date>() {
        @Override
        public Date deserialize(JsonElement dateElement, Type arg1, JsonDeserializationContext arg2)
                throws JsonParseException {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.s'Z'");
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

            String date = dateElement.getAsString();
            try {
                return sdf.parse(date);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                //System.err(String.format("Gsonのパースに失敗しました: %s", date));
                return null;
            }
        }
    });

    gb.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    return gb.create();
}
}
```

改善点等ありましたら教えていただけると助かります｡

Comment: `gson.fromJson(jsonString, Snippet.class);`のような形でパースしているという前提で、フォーマット書式の`s`と`S`を間違えていますが、パースに失敗してnullになる要因ではないように思えます。`System.err.println(String.format("Gsonのパースに失敗しました: %s", date));`のコメントアウトを外して、何を変換しようとして失敗しているのか確認するのが一番早いように思います。もし`+09:00`のような文字列がきていたら、`Z`では失敗します。

Comment: 皆様、返答ありがとうございます。Snippetの中のDate 型の変数をインスタンス化していないことが問題でした。Date型のフォーマットなども参考にさせていただきます。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gsonオブジェクトを生成するときに、`datetime`の型を指定していないため、そもそもデシリアライズ対象として登録出来ていないんじゃないでしょうか。

細かいことはわかりませんが、
BuildGsonにてgsonオブジェクトをnewするときに
[`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").create();`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910734/gsonbuilder-setdateformat-for-2011-10-26t202959-0700)みたいなことをしてくださいとのことらしいです。

その上で、@pgrhoさんのおっしゃっているようにformatの型は`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`が一番いいみたいです。

[jsonファイルのサンプル](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started?hl=ja)をフォーマットしてみた検証ログを置いておきます。

E/TAG﹕ "publishedAt": "2012-06-20T22:45:24.000Z",は次の感じになる？    
E/TAG﹕ yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.s'Z'                                   
E/TAG﹕ Wed Jun 20 22:45:00 GMT+09:00 2012
E/TAG﹕ yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
E/TAG﹕ Wed Jun 20 22:45:24 GMT+09:00 2012
E/TAG﹕ yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX
E/TAG﹕ 落ちます
E/TAG﹕ format結果
E/TAG﹕ 2012/06/20
E/TAG﹕ 2012/06/20
E/TAG﹕ 落ちます

Comment: `gson`はモデルクラスの構造を解析してデシリアライズしますので、`public Date publishedAt;`と定義しておけば、json内の`publishedAt`要素を`Date`にパースしようと試みます。

Comment: @quesera2: ありがとうございます、勉強になりました。`JsonDeserializer`が`generic`で取れる意味や`fromJson`の二番目の引数とかモデルクラスという説明でようやく腑に落ちた感じです。

Answer (score 1):

> SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.s'Z'");

ミリ秒は`S`なので`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`じゃないですか？

あと[Java SE7だと`X`でISO8601タイムゾーン](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)を表すようです。[Androidのリファレンスには無い](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)ので未対応だと思いますが。